# Unable to solve Ensure text remains visible during webfont load

Tags: css, sass, web-frontend, lighthouse

I have tested my code with LightHouse on chrome and I am unable to solve the Error -

```
Ensure text remains visible during webfont load.
Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while webfonts are loading.
```

I have introduced this css code in style.css ,style.scss inside assets , index.html and every .css file of component in angular7 template.

My css code is -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("../font/opensans-regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
  }
```

Whichever place I kept the css, I am unable to solve the error.

Comment: did you try changing the font-display property?

Comment: Ok. I'll try. Thanks

Comment: @Aslam, I tried changing the font-display property will all the possible options. Still to no avail. Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: How about loading the font in the head of html instead of the css file?

Comment: E.g The way you load google fonts.

Comment: Yes I have integrated the @font-face in style tag of index.html

Comment: I mean importing the font via link rel=stylesheet url.

Comment: Please share a link. This cannot be solved like this.